# Weak convergence - $f_n$ "goes up the spout"

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Fix $1 < p < \infty$. Given $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ define $f_n(x) = n^{1/p}f(nx)$ for $n = 1, 2, \dots$. Prove that $f_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^p$.

I'm really confised about this question. I know that I have to show that for every $g \in L^{p'}(\mathbb R)$, $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_ng \to 0$, but I can't even visualize why $f_n$ would go to $0$ using any convergence. How do I "see" that things converge weakly? Also, how would I prove something like this?

Comment: For the visualization, try it for a single example.  For instance, $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is in $L^2$.  Then $f_n(x) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1 + n^2x^2}$ tends to $0$ for each $x$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Just an idea: You may choose a dense subset of $L^{p'}$. Take characteristic functions of intervals (Or compactly supported smooth testfunctions). Use the transformation formula (this rescales the interval) and see what happens.

Comment: @DavidMitra Edited it, sorry.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang It makes sense why it converges to $0$ in that specific example, but I still don't see why it converges for every $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: very loose answer, just for intuition purposes.

The function is integrable over all of $\Re$.  That means the as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$,$f(x) \rightarrow 0$.  The function sequence looks like f(nx).  That means for every $x \neq 0$, $nx \rightarrow \infty$, so $f(nx) \rightarrow 0$ as $nx \rightarrow \infty$.  Now for the $n^{1/p}$.  Let's look at p=1.  If n*f(nx) did not go to zero, then f(x) would look like 1/x going to infinity. But the integral of that does not converge.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the kind of answer I wanted.

Comment: This is indeed good intuition, but readers should note that several of the statements in this answer are *false*.  For instance, it is possible for a function to be integrable but not vanish at infinity.